# Failed to compile in react react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I tried to make a project with the current version of react, react-leaflet and leaflet, and I get this error:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/components/ViewMap.js Module not found: Can't resolve
> 'react-leafet' in 'C:\Users...\src\components'

My Package.json:

```
{

  "name": "leaflet_react_gms02",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,

  "dependencies": {

    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-leaflet": "^3.0.4",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },

  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },

  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  
"devDependencies": {}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue a few weeks ago. And this solution worked for me -

Delete `node module` and `package-lock.json` from your project, And then run `npm install`.

Tell me in the comment if it works for you or not.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I have the same packages, and I've followed step by step the guide on https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/start-installation